# Separating the contents of .then to a new function in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a function:

```
let animal: {
    animalObj: {
        name: string;
        randomInfo: string[]
    }
} = {
    animalObj: {
        name: '',
        randomInfo: ['']
    }
}

cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/animal',
    body: animal
}).then($el => {
    animal.animalObj = $el.body.Order

    animal.animalObj.name = 'Rex'
    animal.animalObj.randomInfo = ["Likes to bark!"]
})
```

If it's possible, I would like to create a new **custom command** for the last two lines:

```
    animal.animalObj.name = 'Rex'
    animal.animalObj.randomInfo = ["Likes to bark!"]
```

Where it will require a string and string[] and at the same time, assigns those two values to **name** and **randomInfo**. That way, I will only need to call that custom command and supply 2 dynamic values.

Answer (score 5):

A custom command that follows `cy.request()` is a "child" command.

It has a special parameter `{prevSubject:true}` to pass in the request response.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setAnimal', {prevSubject:true}, ($response, name, randomInfo) => {
  const animal = {}
  animal.animalObj = $response.body.Order || {}
  animal.animalObj['name'] = name 
  animal.animalObj['randomInfo'] = randomInfo 
  return cy.wrap(animal)
})


cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/animal',
  body: animal
})
.setAnimal('Rex', ["Likes to bark!"])  // response is passed automatically
.as('animal')

// later

cy.get('@animal')
  .then(animal => {
    expect(animal.animalObj.name).to.eq('Rex')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a custom function, you could simply make an `Animal` class, and have a function on the class that updates those two values at once.

```js
class Animal {
  data = { animalObj: { name: '', randomInfo: [''] } };

  constructor(name: string = '', randomInfo: string[] = ['']) {
    this.data.animalObj.name = name;
    this.data.animalObj.randomInfo = randomInfo;
  }

  update(name: string, randomInfo: string[]) {
    this.data.animalObj.name = name;
    this.data.animalObj.randomInfo = randomInfo;
  }
}
...
let animal = new Animal();

cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/animal',
    body: animal.data // assumes body has to have `{ animalObj: {} }`
}).then($el => {
    animal.update('Rex', ['Likes to Bark!']);
    // if you need to only update one value
    animal.data.animalObj.name = $el.body.name
})
```

Comment: Where do you usually set this class? a separate TS file or same as to where you will use it?

Comment: I tend to prefer having my data classes in separate files.